# PDO fails on beginTransaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using beginTransaction around a couple of methods that executes my queries. But it runs the queries eventhough one have failed. Does anyone know where my problem lies?

I'll dry out my code just to show the basics:

Methods:

```
public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->core = db_core::getInstance();
    }

function handle_item($action, $item_id) 
    {
        switch($action) {
        case 'add':
            $this->core->conn->query("INSERT INTO ....");
            break;

        case 'remove':
            $this->core->conn->query("DELETE FROM ....");
            break;
        }
    }
```

beginTransaction

```
try 
    {
    $this->core->conn->beginTransaction();

    $this->handle_item("remove", $item_id);
    $this->handle_item("add", $item_id);

    $this->core->conn->commit();

    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
    $this->core->conn->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually set PDO to [throw exceptions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)?

Comment: Some database engines also do not support transactions and in that case begin transaction is a noop. See the warning in the red box http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: I set setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
And the rollback works fine when i make a query within beingtransaction and commit.

Comment: So what does "query failed" mean in this case? Did it throw an exception? Did it not insert correct data?

Comment: It doesnt throw an exception, and it executes the queries eventhough one of them has failed.

Comment: what is mysql db engine you are using? I wonder because like MyISAM doesn't support transaction for instance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the database is created with PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION enabling exceptions:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

also try should not enclose catch, they should be in different blocks.

```
try 
    {
    $this->core->conn->beginTransaction();

    $this->handle_item("remove", $item_id);
    $this->handle_item("add", $item_id);

    $this->core->conn->commit();
}//!!!
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
    $this->core->conn->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use calling functions for running `INSERT` and `DELETE` within `beginTransaction()` body.
`beginTransaction()` expect to see these Mysql commands implicitly within it's body, not by calling functions. So put `INSERT` and `DELETE` commands implicitly between `beginTransaction()` and `commit()`.